# Отправка данных в БД Apache Cassandra

Tags: python, база-данных, nosql, cassandra

По каким-то причинам не удается отправить данные в БД.
Принцип работы моего скрипта такой - есть цикл, внутри которого создан парсер для чтения документов, хранящихся в папке. Он вытягивает значения из нужных тегов, считывает весь документ, и эти данные уходят в переменную. После этого с помощью INSERT INTO mytable данные должны уходить в базу, где uid является primary key, а остальные переменные идут как обычные values.
Я не могу понять, в чем моя ошибка, IDE мне бьет ошибки в стиле

> cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:33 no viable alternative at input 'PRIMARY'">

Чтение документации Cassandra особо эффекта не дало, поскольку я шел по шагам, и с моим стеком знаний все должно было работать.
Но - нет...

Есть кто знает, как мне преобразовать код, чтоб после прочтения файла парсером и сохранения в переменные данные из них улетали в БД, и потом цикл возвращался к старту, начиная считывать следующий документ?

```
import os
import lxml
import time
import cassandra
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

#----------#

counter = 0
uidC = []
sourceC = []
languageC = []
profile_urlC = []
xmlfileC = []

ftype = r".xml"
directory = r"Путь к папке"
parser = [os.path.join(directory, _) for _ in os.listdir(directory) if   _.endswith(ftype)]

cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
session = cluster.connect()
session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}")
session.execute("CREATE TABLE testtable (uid PRIMARY KEY, language, source, profile_url, file)")

#----------#

for doc in parser:
    with open(doc, encoding="utf8") as file:
        xmlfile = file.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xmlfile, "lxml")
        #----------#
        uid = soup.find("prop", attrs={'name':'uid'})
        language = soup.find("prop", attrs={'name':'language'})
        source = soup.find("prop", attrs={'name':'source'})
        profile_url = soup.find("profile_url")
        if profile_url == None:
            counter += 1
            continue
        #----------#
        session.execute("""
            INSERT INTO testtable
            (uid, language, source, profile_url, file)
             VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
            """,
            (uid, language, source, profile_url, xmlfile)
        )
        #----------#
        uidC.append(uid.text)
        sourceC.append(source.text)
        languageC.append(language.text)
        profile_urlC.append(profile_url.text)
        xmlfileC.append(xmlfile)
        counter += 1

#----------#

print(uidC)
print(sourceC)
print(languageC)
print(profile_urlC)
print(xmlfileC)
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В определении таблицы не хвататет типов, оно должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
  uid uuid PRIMARY KEY, 
  language text, 
  source text, 
  profile_url text, 
  file text)
```

P.S. Также имеет смысл использовать prepared query

Comment: Прогресс пошел. 
Однако теперь ошибка такая - cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No keyspace has been specified. USE a keyspace, or explicitly specify keyspace.tablename".

Весьма занятно, поскольку путь указан.
Я не особо разбираюсь в кассандре, поэтому мне нужен ответ более простым языком. Спасибо! :)

Comment: `INSERT INTO testtable` -> `INSERT INTO testkeyspace.testtable`

Comment: в телеграме есть русско-язычная группа: https://t.me/cassandra_users_rus